# Could not launch Xcode Service on Xcode Server with Xcode 7.2.1

Tags: xcode, xcode-server

After update Xcode (from 7.2 to 7.2.1) XcodeServer is unable to run Xcode Service. When I choose updated Xcode then alert with message: `Enable Accessibility access for UI Testing (...)` appear. After tap on `Request Access`'s button of this alert XcodeServer give me an alert with message `You must agree to the terms of the Xcode software license agreement. Launch Xcode again and agree to the software license agreement, or choose a different version of Xcode.`. Of course I done this (few times) and also the Xcode (and Xcode Helper) are on the list of allowed app in Accessibility section of Privacy in System Preferences.

Does anyone can help? 
Or has anyone the same issue?

I was tring commands lines:

```
xcrun xcscontrol --reset
```

and:

```
xcodebuild -license
```

After instal previous version (7.2) everything works as usual.

**Edited:**

After instal previous version (7.2) I can not see any of my bot I have created before. (but this is probably result of `xcrun xcscontrol --reset`.

Comment: You're not the only one, it seems Apple broke it: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/34683

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Eimantas Vaiciunas post at [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/34683#109132):

> Since checkFirstLaunchStatus with sudo returned 69 I launched Xcode
>   with sudo too:
>   sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
>   This launched Xcode with license agreement prompt and after agreeing,
>   everything went fine.

Comment: Was able to get things xcode server running after trying some of the above tips -
But repositories are not showing up. So, not real great.

Comment: You can check if Your repository exist in ```/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/HostedRepositories/```. But if You used the ```xcrun xcscontrol --reset```'s command it probably removed all Your content from Xcode Server.

Comment: Thanks for solving what happened to my repositories - I was wondering if I had a disk going bad.

Answer (score 2):

**sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcscontrol --initialize**

Did the trick for me. Use on your own risk.